# Combine values from an object within an object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, es6-modules

I am trying to combine ids for an object. The original object looks like this:

```
{
   "Car1":{
      "139":{
         "count":3,
         "ids":[
            "336",
            "347",
            "453"
         ]
      },
      "140":{
         "count":1,
         "ids":[
            "338"
         ]
      }
   },
   "Car2":{
      "157":{
         "count":1,
         "ids":[
            "4449"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to combine the ids for each "car" so that it looks like this.

```
{
   "Car1":{
      "ids":[
         "336",
         "347",
         "453",
         "338"
      ]
   },
   "Car2":{
      "ids":[
         "4449"
      ]
   }
}
```

Basically just trying to create a function that reduces the unneeded information and combines the ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `Array.reduce`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((acc, [carName, carData]) => {
    acc[carName] = { ids: Object.values(carData).flatMap(({ids}) => ids) };
    return acc;
  },{});
```

I further commented each line in the demo:

```js
const data = {
   "Car1":{
      "139":{"count":3,"ids":["336","347","453"]},
      "140":{"count":1, "ids":["338"]}
   },
   "Car2":{
      "157":{"count":1,"ids":["4449"]}
   }
};

const transformedData =
//for all property name=>value pairs in data
Object.entries(data)
  //return the reduced version...
  //for each couple as carName=>carData
  .reduce((acc, [carName, carData]) => {
    //sets the property carName in the accumulator
    acc[carName] = {
      //where the id property is the merge of all the ids found in the whole list
      ids: Object.values(carData).flatMap(({ids}) => ids)
    };
    return acc;
  },
  //inits the accumulator with empty object
  {});

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
const obj = {
   "Car1":{
      "139":{
         "count":3,
         "ids":[
            "336",
            "347",
            "453"
         ]
      },
      "140":{
         "count":1,
         "ids":[
            "338"
         ]
      }
   },
   "Car2":{
      "157":{
         "count":1,
         "ids":[
            "4449"
         ]
      }
   }
}

const objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
let newObj = {}

objKeys.forEach(key =>{
    const carObjKeys = Object.keys(obj[key])
    let keysArray = [];
    
    carObjKeys.forEach(k =>{
        keysArray = keysArray.concat(obj[key][k]['ids'])
    })
    
    newObj[key] = {
        ids: keysArray
    }
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine the IDs for each car in your object and remove the unneeded information, you can use the following function:

```
function combineIds(obj) {
  const combined = {};

  for (const car in obj) {
    combined[car] = { ids: [] };
    for (const id in obj[car]) {
      combined[car].ids.push(...obj[car][id].ids);
    }
  }

  return combined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
    function convertObject(obj) {
        let res = {};
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            let ids = [];
            for(const subKey in obj[key]) {
                ids = [...ids, ...obj[key][subKey]["ids"]]
            }
            res[key] = ids;
        })
        return res;
    }
```